# OpenGL window doesn't open in xcode (7.2) when run as a child process

Tags: c, xcode, opengl, multiprocessing, glut

I am on OS X 10.10.5, and Xcode 7.2.  I have a program that spawns a child process to run a visualization using OpenGL/GLUT, i.e.

```
pid_t childpid;
childpid = fork();
if(childpid == 0) { // this is the child process
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  ...
}
else{  // this is the parent process that does something else
  ...
}
```

When I run this in Xcode, the program never returns from glutInit.  If instead I use the parent process to do the visualization, and the child to run everything else, i.e.

```
if(childpid != 0) { // this is the parent process
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  ...
}
...
```

then the OpenGL window pops up, and the whole program runs fine.  Additionally, if I run the original version (with the child doing the visualization) when building with Makefiles in the terminal outside of Xcode, everything runs fine.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

I haven't been able to debug things very far within Xcode, because the debugger always follows the parent process.  If I try to attach to the child process through Debug->Attach to process, I get an error: "Xcode couldn't attach to “J2”. “J2” does not support a debuggable architecture." I found some questions on this last issue of attaching to other processes in xcode, but the solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do ***anything*** on the child side of a `fork()` other than some variety of `exec()` or `_exit()`.

I'll quote the Leopard CoreFoundation Framework Release Notes. I don't know if they're still online, since Apple tends to replace rather than extend the Core Foundation release notes.

> #### CoreFoundation and fork()
>
> Due to the behavior of fork(), CoreFoundation cannot be used on the
>   child-side of fork(). If you fork(), you must follow that with an
>   exec*() call of some sort, and you should not use CoreFoundation APIs
>   within the child, before the exec*(). The applies to all higher-level
>   APIs which use CoreFoundation, and since you cannot know what those
>   higher-level APIs are doing, and whether they are using CoreFoundation
>   APIs, you should not use any higher-level APIs either. This includes
>   use of the daemon() function.
>
> Additionally, per POSIX, only async-cancel-safe functions are safe to
>   use on the child side of fork(), so even use of lower-level
>   libSystem/BSD/UNIX APIs should be kept to a minimum, and ideally to
>   only async-cancel-safe functions.
>
> This has always been true, and there have been notes made of this on
>   various Cocoa developer mailling lists in the past. But CoreFoundation
>   is taking some stronger measures now to "enforce" this limitation, so
>   we thought it would be worthwhile to add a release note to call this
>   out as well. A message is written to stderr when something uses API
>   which is definitely known not to be safe in CoreFoundation after
>   fork(). If file descriptor 2 has been closed, however, you will get no
>   message or notice, which is too bad. We tried to make processes
>   terminate in a very recognizable way, and did for a while and that was
>   very handy, but backwards binary compatibility prevented us from doing
>   so.

In other words, it has never been safe to do much of anything on the child side of a `fork()` other than exec a new program.

Besides the general POSIX prohibition, an oft-mentioned explanation is: a) pretty much all Cocoa programs are multithreaded these days, what with GCD and the like. B) when you `fork()`, only the calling thread survives into the child process; the other threads just vanish. Since those threads could have been manipulating shared resources, the child process can't rely on having sane state. For example, the `malloc()` implementation may have a lock to protect shared structures and that lock could have been held by one of the now-gone threads at the time of the `fork()`. So, if the remaining thread tries to allocate memory, it may hang indefinitely. Other shared data structures may simply be in a corrupted state. Etc.

Comment: Thanks! So is the reason that it works fine when building everything manually with Makefiles that Xcode is doing more complicated things behind the scenes then?

Comment: I don't know why it seems to "work fine" in some cases, but you can't rely on it in any case. The nature of the hazard with doing stuff on the child side of a `fork()` is inherently unpredictable. There's no **guarantee** that things will definitely go wrong on any given run. It's just that there's no guarantee that they will go right, either.